# TWRP ignore Getprop

Tags: recovery-mode, rom, twrp

I have an obscure Moto X varient, so when flashing ROMs in TWRP I have to manually edit every one to remove the getprop line from the updater script. Is there some way I can change the built in name of my phone or get TWRP to ignore the getprop file every time?